Which one of these sentences is correct? Not even vs Even don't

Not even girls use them
Even girls don't use them

This might be too basic of a question, but can anyone please answer this

They are both valid ways of expressing the same idea.

Note, while this works, "Girls don't even use them" would be a different meaning

But the Snagglepussian "Girls don't use them, even" could be synonymous.

Ofhand, I can't think of a context where it makes any difference whether negating not applies directly to the basic assertion even girls use them, or if we rephrase to include "do-support" and then apply the negation as don't.

...but that's only with intensifying even. There's definitely a difference between #1 Not many girls do that and #2 Many girls don't do that. #1 implies most girls don't do it, but #2 implies most girls do.

Both are correct, but there is a difference between them.
"Not even" is used to emphasise the extent or degree of a situation by indicating that something is so unlikely or so extreme that even the least expected case doesn't occur. It is  It usually conveys surprise or disbelief.
"Even...don't" places emphasis on the subject to show that, despite expectations, the subject does not meet a certain condition or perform a certain action.
You haven't provided context for your examples, and context is everything. Your choice might differ depending on the reason why you think girls are the most extreme degree to which something might apply. For example, are girls the most likely group to like this thing, or the least? Is the reason you might expect them to like it because they are the target audience, or are you inferring that they don't know any better? It might also depend on how many other groups have already been eliminated - is it just girls and boys, or are you considering more demographics?

Here's the context, My friend told me that he was going to buy a phone made by a certain company, And I wanted to convince him not to buy that brand by saying that girls he has a crush on use a different brand

@SkylenDias I'm not sure either fit that context.

Would it be wrong if I said 'Even the girls you like don't use them' @Astralbee ?

@SkylenDias Sure, that makes more sense grammatically, although I'm not sure what the point is. As I explained, both these expressions focus on the subject being the last possible person, thing or group to be excluded and usually because they are the most likely to be included. So presumably you've already said that lots of other people don't use these phones, and you're finishing up with "even the girls you like don't use them". It only makes sense if (i) the girls are the most likely to use them, or (ii) them using the phones would mean something for your audience.
